# ScheduledExecutorService withFixedDelay перестает работать через несколько дней

Tags: java, многопоточность

Написал телеграм бота, который парсит сайт и, спустя некоторое время, отправляет информацию в телеграм.

```
public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

private Map<Long, Integer> usersSelection = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();

private static AtomicBoolean postStarted=new AtomicBoolean();

private static Bot bot;

private static Logger logger;

private static JdbcManager jdbcManager;

private static Timer postmanTimer;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Configurer configurer = new Configurer();
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");
    jdbcManager= (JdbcManager)context.getBean("jdbcManager");
    logger=new Logger(configurer);
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Aggregator(configurer, jdbcManager), 20, 20, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    ApiContextInitializer.init();
    TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
    try {
        bot=new Bot();
        telegramBotsApi.registerBot(bot);
    }catch (TelegramApiException e){
        logger.logs(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    if (update.hasMessage()){
        Message message = update.getMessage();
        if (message!=null&&message.hasText()) {
            MessageHandler messageHandler = new MessageHandler(bot, usersSelection, message, postStarted, jdbcManager);
            messageHandler.permitter();
        }
    }else if (update.hasCallbackQuery()){
        try {
            if (!postStarted.get()){
                postmanTimer=new Timer();
            }
            CallBacker callBacker=new CallBacker(bot,update.getCallbackQuery(),postStarted,
                    usersSelection,jdbcManager,postmanTimer);
            callBacker.caser();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.logs(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public String getBotUsername() {
    return "bot_username";
}

@Override
public String getBotToken() {
    return "000000000:AAEASfagefewyur-dgrfqefqewfgqe";
}

}
```

За парсинг отвечает класс Aggregator, который я запускаю в отдельном потоке

```
public class Aggregator implements Runnable {

private Parser parser;

private Configurer configurer;

private Logger logger;

private JdbcManager jdbcManager;

public Aggregator(Configurer configurer, JdbcManager jdbcManager) {
    this.configurer = configurer;
    this.parser = new Parser();
    this.logger = new Logger(configurer);
    this.jdbcManager = jdbcManager;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        logger.logs("Start aggregator...");
        List<String> articleUrls = getArticleUrls();
        if (articleUrls != null && !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(articleUrls)) {
            for (String articleUrl : articleUrls) {
                try {
                    parser.parseArticleUrl(articleUrl,jdbcManager,configurer);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.logs("From aggregator run"+e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (Throwable t){
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private List<String> getArticleUrls() {
    List<String> articleUrls = new ArrayList<>();

    List<String> likeKeyWords = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        likeKeyWords = jdbcManager.getLinesFromList(configurer.getLikeKeyWordsDir());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.logs("from getArticleUrls "+e.getMessage());
    }
    for (String likeKeyWord : likeKeyWords) {
        try {
            List<String> urlsFromDzenParser = parser.getDzenArticleUrlsByKeyWord(likeKeyWord);
            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(urlsFromDzenParser)) {
                jdbcManager.resetMissFromDzenParser();
                articleUrls.addAll(urlsFromDzenParser);
            } else {
                jdbcManager.missFromDzenParserIncrease();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            jdbcManager.missFromDzenParserIncrease();
            logger.logs(e.getMessage() + "getDzenArticleUrlsByKeyWordMiss LIKEKEYWORD " + likeKeyWord);
        }
    }
    return articleUrls;
}
```

}

Всё работает нормально, но через 2-3 дня я обнаруживаю, что ScheduledExecutorService в какое-то время просто перестаёт запускать новый поток. Перезапускаю приложение- и снова 2-3 дня и новый поток не запускается. Я читал, что дело может быть в том, что поток выбрасывает исключения и новое выполнение потоков подавляется. Для этого я обернул метод run в try catch Throwable. Ситуацию это не спасло.

Я пробовал использовать вместо ScheduledExecutorService - Timer, это также не помогло.  Кто может помочь понять, в чем дело, как лучше запускать, чтобы даже несмотря на возникающие ошибки и исключения итерации продолжались. Запускать поток в потоке? Как лучше?

jstack

```
"pool-1-thread-1" #11 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f0390f8c800 nid=0x6133 runnable [0x00007f03271f4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:457)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:237)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:190)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:108)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1146)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1116)
    - locked <0x00000005e391a668> (a sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$200(SSLSocketImpl.java:72)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:815)
    - locked <0x00000005e391a6d8> (a sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    - locked <0x00000005e391a6f8> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.WireLogInputStream.read(WireLogInputStream.java:69)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:170)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(AutoCloseInputStream.java:108)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(AutoCloseInputStream.java:127)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.getResponseBody(HttpMethodBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.getResponseBodyAsString(HttpMethodBase.java:803)
    at com.dzen.monitor.bot.core.Parser.getDzenArticleUrlsByKeyWord(Parser.java:180)
    at com.dzen.monitor.bot.scheduler.Aggregator.getArticleUrls(Aggregator.java:70)
    at com.dzen.monitor.bot.scheduler.Aggregator.run(Aggregator.java:33)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Уверены, что у вас просто сама задача не зациклилась или не зависла? Т.е. что `Aggregator.run` заканчивает выполнение, а не висит на каком-то локе? Первым делом, я бы добавил логирование в `run` и еще, когда перестает запускать глянул бы `jstack`-ом, что тот поток делает.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, никогда до сих пор не пользовался jstack ом. Сейчас посмотрел через него отчет. Там есть поток с названием pool -1-thread1. Если jstack показывает отчет только по активным потокам, а не по всем, которые были (просто я не знаком с jstack ом, поэтому не знаю), то получается, что мой поток действительно завис. Есть какая-то возможность убивать зависший поток, по времени задержки, например? Например даю ему на выполнение 30 минут, если он сам не завершает выполнение, то убиваю

Comment: jstack показывает все потоки и их стектрейсы, т.е. поток пула там будет в любом случае. Важно, что он делает, когда произошло подвисание. Если поток где-то ждет или зациклилися, то по стектрейсу это будет видно. Убивать потоки извне (т.е. без участия самого потока) не получится. Следующий шаг, если поток зациклился или ждет, это понять почему это так.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, добавил вывод из jstack по потоку

Comment: @RomanKonoval, значит ли надпись java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE что поток запущен, или так всего лишь показано, что класс имплементит интерфейс RUNNABLE?

Comment: Это значит, что поток не блокирован и готов к исполнению, т.е если планировщик даст ему время, то будет исполнятся (а возможно исполняется прямо сейчас). Это значит задача не завершилась и все еще исполняется. В таком случае нового запуска не будет.